# Count the number of restricted multigraphs

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, permutations

Suppose I have a multigraph with the following set of restrictions:

- every vertex can have up to $c$ edges
- two vertices can be connected by a maximum of $c-1$ edges
- loops may or may not be allowed (two versions)

Let's call $n$ the number of vertices, and $m$ the number of edges.

Example: for $n=4$, $c=3$ and $m=5$, the following graphs are allowed (among others):

[image: Allowed graphs]

But for instance the following are not:

[image: Unallowed graphs]

Here comes my question:

**For given $n$, $c$, and $m$, how to count the number of possible graphs, a) including equivalent graphs and b) excluding equivalent graphs?**

With equivalent graphs, I mean without topological ordering, f.e. the following graphs are all equivalent:

[image: Equivalent graphs]

What I have came up with so far:

We can recognise several types of graphs, by counting the number of single edges, double edges, triples edges, etc..

For 5 edges, we can have 5 single edges, 3 single edges and 1 double edge, 2 single edges and 1 triple edge, 1 single edge and 2 double edges, or 1 single edge and 1 quadruple edge. If we add the restriction $c=3$, then only 5 single edges, 3 single edges and 1 double edge, and 1 single edge and 2 double edges remain.

The total number of this types of graphs that we have for given $m$ and $c$ is $p(m;c)$, the *integer partition function* with the additional restriction that every part should be smaller than $c$.

Next we use the *incidence matrix*, which counts the number of edges that connect to vertices. For example the last graph in the last figure has the incidence matrix (counting vertices clockwise starting from the upper-leftmost):

$\begin{array}{cccc}
 & v_1  & v_2 & v_3 & v_4 \\
v_1 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\
v_2 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
v_3 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\
v_4 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0
\end{array}$

These matrices are always symmetric, and have vanishing diagonal entries if loops are not allowed. Thus only the upper diagonal submatrix has independent entries, meaning all information is contained in $N=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ entries (if loops are not allowed, we can scratch the diagonal entries and we are left with $N=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ independent entries). Next we permute these entries (which is a permutation with multiplicities). Let us call $m_i$ the number of $i$-tuple edges, then the total number of graphs with $n$ vertices and $m$ edges is given by (counting topological equivalent graphs as different graphs):

$\sum\limits_{\{m_i\}\in P(m;c)} \frac{N!}{m_1!m_2!\cdots m_{c-1}! (N-\sum m_i)!}$ where $N = \begin{cases} \frac{n(n+1)}{2} & \text{loops allowed} \\ \frac{n(n-1)}{2} & \text{loops not allowed} \end{cases}$

**But there are two problems here:**

- we did not take into account the first restriction, that every vertex should have no more than $c$ edges connected to it. I have no idea how to implement it.
- I do not want to count the topological equivalent graphs. However I'd like to know how many there are for a given topology (because it is a symmetry factor I will need in my calculations), but I don't want to count them as different graphs.

Any ideas?

---

**Extra:**  If somehow a solution to the former is found, I'd like to add two more restrictions:

- every graph should have a maximum of $\lfloor\frac{n \, c}{2}\rfloor -1$ edges, and at least two vertices should each have a maximum of $c-1$ edges connected to it (in other words, if I have only two 'openings' left -vertices that are not fully connected- they cannot be on the same vertex: for example
  [image: Extra non allowed graph]
  is not allowed).
- if a graph consists of subgraphs, the same is true for every subgraph (with a maximum of $\lfloor\frac{n_\text{sub} \, c}{2}\rfloor -1$ edges, where $n_\text{sub}$ is the number of vertices in the subgraph)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at the so-called configuration model. In particular if you fix the degree sequence of nodes $\mathbf{k} = (k_1,\ldots,k_n)$ the number of loopy multigraphs satisfying the given degree sequence is

$$
\binom{2m}{k_1,\ldots,k_n}
$$

where this is intended as the multinomial coefficient.